# Id field in Entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have made google app engine backend for my android client app.
I made my entity class and autogenerated end point class for it in Android studio.
This auto generated class has method:

public XXX getXXX(@Named("id") Long id)

I plan to use Query api to add as well as fetch the entity.

IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("XXX_Index").build();
Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);

It has got me a bit confused. I understand that when I insert entity first time, app engine data store auto generates id for the entity.This id can be string.So how to make my id compatible with auto generated getXXX method which takes Long as input.

Manish

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine datastore key property has two components, Name and Id. Name property can be string and Id property can be Long. You can use either Name or Id as part of your entity key.

Using JDO

you can set long property as below

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

See documentation [Jdo doc](http://goo.gl/RvOtnu)

Comment: Thanks for input.What is gradle dependency for jdo?